# How to delete taggregate_temp_ tables at once?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In my SQL I have multi tables like:

taggregate_temp_1364792160

taggregate_temp_1364795760

taggregate_temp_1364799360

taggregate_temp_1364802960

taggregate_temp_1364806560

taggregate_temp_1364810160

taggregate_temp_1364813760

taggregate_temp_1364817360

taggregate_temp_1364820960

taggregate_temp_1364824560

taggregate_temp_1364828160

taggregate_temp_1364831760

taggregate_temp_1364835360

taggregate_temp_1364838960

taggregate_temp_1364842560

taggregate_temp_1364846160

taggregate_temp_1364849760

taggregate_temp_1364853360

I need to delete all tables begin with: taggregate_temp_ at once

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by another user: [Drop all tables whose names begin with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393/drop-all-tables-whose-names-begin-with-a-certain-string)

You will want to do something like

```
USE DATABASE_NAME
GO

declare @cmd varchar(4000)
declare cmds cursor for 

select 'DROP TABLE [' + Table_Name + ']'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where Table_Name like 'taggregate_temp_%'

open cmds
while 1=1
begin
    fetch cmds into @cmd
    if @@fetch_status != 0 break
    exec(@cmd)
end
close cmds;
deallocate cmds
```

Edit: You didn't mention mysql in the question, but I just saw the tag, have a look at the following topic for a mysql example: [MySQL bulk drop table where table like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053116/mysql-bulk-drop-table-where-table-like)

Comment: Do I need to replace DATABASE_NAME ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to define which database you want to run the command against.

Comment: Do I need to replace Table_Name ?

Comment: Nope, Table_Name is the name of the column in the information schema. In the edit I mentioned that this sql is specific to SQL Server, but there is a link to a MySQL specific example