# How to drop all tables from a database with one SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't want to type all tables' name to drop all of them. Is it possible with one query?

Comment: Some quick googling revealed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053116/mysql-bulk-drop-table-where-table-like

Comment: -although (for SQLServer) this might be more useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536350/drop-all-the-tables-stored-procedures-triggers-constraints-and-all-the-depend

Comment: With the right usernames, this could happen automatically ([obligatory xkcd link](http://xkcd.com/327/)).

Comment: Do you have any foreign keys on tables in the database? If so, you'd need to take that into consideration, and drop those before trying to drop tables.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have schemabound objects you can't drop the table.

Comment: drop database, easy

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Use the [**INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186778.aspx) view to get the list of tables. Generate Drop scripts in the select statement and drop it using Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql += ' Drop table ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.'+ QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + '; '
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

Exec Sp_executesql @sql
```

[**Sys.Tables**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) Version

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql += ' Drop table ' + QUOTENAME(s.NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.NAME) + '; '
FROM   sys.tables t
       JOIN sys.schemas s
         ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE  t.type = 'U'

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

**Note:** If you have any `foreign Keys` defined between tables then first run the below query to **disable** all `foreign keys` present in your database.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

For more information, [***check here***](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/29/sql-server-disable-all-the-foreign-key-constraint-in-database-enable-all-the-foreign-key-constraint-in-database/).

Comment: (not my downvote) ... i'd generally stick with the `[sys]` schema views if portability across rdbms' is not required. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3654313/251174

Comment: Also see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand for pointing me in right direction. Still learning all these stuff just a beginner in sql server :) Btw thanks for edit.

Comment: This is amazing - works perfectly for me. Just for my own learning, could you explain what your code is actually doing? I would be fascinated to know! thanks.

Comment: @DoubleA - It is very simple. First am building Drop statements for all the tables in my database and storing it into a variable. To check this you can use `Print @sql` before `exec`. Then am executing the dynamically built drop statements through `sp_executesql`

Comment: If you are using Azure, sp_msforeachtable is not available.  I found this sweet nugget from @Aaron Bertrand to delete all  FK constraints.  Works really good with this answer. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90033/how-do-i-drop-all-constraints-from-all-tables

Comment: If the sp_msforeachtable is not available, you can also run the delete query multiple times, since the tables which depend on others are then deleted :)

Comment: But I can't fit all this on my license plate!

Comment: If dropping external tables, will have to modify the following line of code: `SELECT @sql += ' Drop external table ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.'+ QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + '; '`

Comment: constraint check still applies after running the disabling code.

Comment: `Print @sql` has trouble printing the whole string if you have lots of tables.

Comment: Just needs a small note on why there are "different versions" - what's the reason to choose one or the other

Answer (score 118):

If you want to use only one SQL query to delete all tables you can use this:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = "DROP TABLE ?"
```

This is a hidden Stored Procedure in sql server, and will be executed for each table in the database you're connected.

**Note:** You may need to execute the query a few times to delete all tables due to dependencies.

**Note2:** To avoid the first note, before running the query, first check if there foreign keys relations to any table. If there are then just [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/how-can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql) foreign key constraint by running the query bellow:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Comment: I tried it on my Azure SQL database, and it didn't work. However the above answer (by Prdp) worked.

Comment: For the side note, i need to run first command multiple times before dropped all tables but it works fine.

Comment: @Thatshowweroll that's probably because of the tables' dependencies. If one table has others that depend on it it can't be deleted.

Comment: @RageAgainstTheMachine yes it is definitely from tables with multiple cross dependencies. I want to inform users to run it multiple times, errors are not problems. Run first command 3-4 times then second command 1 time and BOM. It works like charm!

Comment: @RageAgainstTheMachine , can you confirm that this sp will only affect the tables in the database that your query window is currently connected to? I just want to make absolutely sure that this will only affect the database I'm currently in, rather than all of the databases in the server.

Comment: @KyleVassella yes, this will execute only on the database in which you have your console open

Comment: `Azure SQL` database does not have `sp_msforeachtable`. This will not work in `Azure SQL`.

Answer (score 63):

If you don't want to type, you can create the statements with this:

```
USE Databasename

SELECT  'DROP TABLE [' + name + '];'
FROM    sys.tables
```

Then copy and paste into a new SSMS window to run it.

Comment: table name should be wrapped in [ ], but works great even on Azure

Comment: We can use `QUOTENAME` also which looks neat. `'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'`

Comment: We can also use this order to avoid constraint issue while deleting.
order by create_date desc

Answer (score 46):

The simplest way is to drop the whole database and create it once again:

```
drop database db_name
create database db_name
```

That's all.

As pointed out in the comments, this does have some important side-effects to be aware of (depending on your needs, these effects may or may not be desirable):

- This will wipe off all the other system objects like Procedures, views etc., associated the table.
- You'll lose any users you added to the database.

Comment: :) at least for me the purpose of droping all tables is because database can not be deleted

Comment: don't run this command on company's database. Or be ready to find another job.

Comment: @FarazDurrani easy man, dropping all tables doesn't seem like a deal for PROD db either.

Comment: Be careful. This will wipe off all the other system objects like Procedures, views etc., associated the table.

Comment: How to find the DB name?

Comment: Run the command ```show databases;``` to see all database @LuboKanev

Comment: Nope. You'll lose any users you added to the database. Downvote as this answer should have caveats.

Comment: Not an option for Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 31):

You could also use the following script to drop everything, including the following:

- non-system stored procedures
- views
- functions
- foreign key constraints
- primary key constraints
- system_versioning
- tables

https://michaelreichenbach.de/posts/how-to-drop-everything-in-a-mssql-database/

```
/* Drop all non-system stored procs */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'P' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])

WHILE @name is not null
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'
    EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT 'Dropped Procedure: ' + @name
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'P' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
END
GO

/* Drop all views */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'V' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP VIEW [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'
    EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT 'Dropped View: ' + @name
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'V' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
END
GO

/* Drop all functions */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'
    EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT 'Dropped Function: ' + @name
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
END
GO

/* Drop all Foreign Key constraints */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)

WHILE @name is not null
BEGIN
    SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
    WHILE @constraint IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint) +']'
        EXEC (@SQL)
        PRINT 'Dropped FK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name
        SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
    END
SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
END
GO

/* Drop all Primary Key constraints */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
    WHILE @constraint is not null
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint)+']'
        EXEC (@SQL)
        PRINT 'Dropped PK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name
        SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
    END
SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
END
GO

/* Remove system versioning */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(' + @name + '), 'TableTemporalType') = 2 
        SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF); ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) + '] DROP PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME;'
        EXEC (@SQL)
        PRINT 'System Versioning Disabled for Table: ' + @name
        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
END
GO

/* Drop all tables */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'
    EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT 'Dropped Table: ' + @name
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
END
GO
```

Comment: Sorry but this script doesn't work with multiple schema. You have hard-coded "[dbo]." in multiple rows of your script.

Comment: Worked well.. Best script for delete the tables.

Answer (score 26):

As a follow-up to Dave.Gugg's answer, this would be the code someone would need to get all the DROP TABLE lines in MySQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name'
```

Comment: I know the original poster labeled the question with "sql-server", but this might be useful to someone looking to do this in MySQL. In fact I found this question when googling for a MySQL solution to this question, so I'm now sharing the solution I came up with after reading one of the answers here.

Comment: This worked like a magic which I totally needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: Used it on a H2 Database - Works like a charm. Thx.

Answer (score 9):

I'd just make a small change to @NoDisplayName's answer and use `QUOTENAME()` on the `TABLE_NAME` column and also include the `TABLE_SCHEMA` column encase the tables aren't in the `dbo` schema.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @sql += 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME([TABLE_SCHEMA]) + '.' + QUOTENAME([TABLE_NAME]) + ';'
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
WHERE [TABLE_TYPE] = 'BASE TABLE';

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
```

Or using `sys` schema views (as per @swasheck's comment):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @sql += 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME([S].[name]) + '.' + QUOTENAME([T].[name]) + ';'
FROM [sys].[tables] AS [T]
INNER JOIN [sys].[schemas] AS [S] ON ([T].[schema_id] = [S].[schema_id])
WHERE [T].[type] = 'U' AND [T].[is_ms_shipped] = 0;

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
```

Comment: i'd generally stick with the `[sys]` schema views if portability across rdbms' is not required. stackoverflow.com/a/3654313/251174

Comment: @swasheck Thanks for the link that was quite interesting. I've updated the answer with a solution using sys schema views.

Comment: You can use Schema_name() function to get the schema name instead of joining http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175068.aspx

Comment: @NoDisplayName Just because you *can*, doesn't mean that you *should*... http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions/

Comment: @AaronBertrand - My bad thought it could be a better way. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @NoDisplayName It's a little less typing but not worth it IMHO. Especially if you have to reference it multiple times.

Answer (score 7):

If anybody else had a problem with best answer's solution (including disabling foreign keys), here is **another solution from me**:

```
-- CLEAN DB
USE [DB_NAME]
    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(500) DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR
    SET @Cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

    SELECT DISTINCT sql = 'ALTER TABLE [' + tc2.TABLE_NAME + '] DROP [' + rc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc1
    LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc2 ON tc2.CONSTRAINT_NAME =rc1.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    OPEN @Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @Sql
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
      BEGIN
        Exec SP_EXECUTESQL @Sql
        FETCH NEXT 
        FROM @Cursor INTO @Sql
      END
    CLOSE @Cursor DEALLOCATE @Cursor
    GO

    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DROP TABLE ?'
    GO

    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
```

Answer (score 4):

Not quite 1 query, still quite short and sweet:

```
-- Disable all referential integrity constraints
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO

-- Drop all PKs and FKs
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql = STUFF((SELECT '; ' + 'ALTER TABLE ' + Table_Name  +'  drop constraint ' + Constraint_Name  from Information_Schema.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE ORDER BY Constraint_Name FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
EXECUTE (@sql)
GO

-- Drop all tables
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'DROP TABLE ?'
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following script to `drop` all `constraints`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql += ' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.'+ QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) +    ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all; '
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

Exec Sp_executesql @sql
```

Then run the following to drop all tables:

```
select @sql='';

SELECT @sql += ' Drop table ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.'+ QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + '; '
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

Exec Sp_executesql @sql
```

This worked for me in Azure SQL Database where `'sp_msforeachtable'` was not available!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
DROP DATABASE database_name;
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

This will delete the database and create a new database with the same name

Comment: Be careful you won't be able to retrieve any data from the database

Answer (score 1):

I Know this question is very old but every Time i need this code .. by the way if you have tables and views and Functions and PROCEDURES you can delete it all by this Script ..
so why i post this Script ?? because if u delete all tables you will need to delete all views and if you have Functions and PROCEDURES  you need to delete it too
i Hope it will help someone

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

 SELECT @sql += ' Drop table ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.'+ QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) 
+ '; '
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

Exec Sp_executesql @sql


 DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    , @crlf VARCHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) ;

 SELECT @sql = @sql + 'DROP VIEW ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + 
 QUOTENAME(v.name) +';' + @crlf
 FROM   sys.views v

 PRINT @sql;
 EXEC(@sql);

 declare @procName varchar(500)
 declare cur cursor 

 for select [name] from sys.objects where type = 'p'
 open cur
 fetch next from cur into @procName
 while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin
  exec('drop procedure [' + @procName + ']')
fetch next from cur into @procName
 end
  close cur
  deallocate cur

  Declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    SELECT @sql = @sql + N' DROP FUNCTION ' 
               + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) 
               + N'.' + QUOTENAME(name)
    FROM sys.objects
  WHERE type_desc LIKE '%FUNCTION%';

   Exec sp_executesql @sql
  GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I‘d do it with a loop for all tables if you’re using like oracle or sqlite:

```
FOR i IN (SELECT ut.table_name
              FROM USER_TABLES ut) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table '|| i.table_name ||' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ';
  END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me in Azure SQL on a database with tables in multiple schema's, including system versioned tables.

It uses a cursor to go through all constraints and tables, so it won't end up in an endless loop if you would get an error somewhere.

```
--drop all FK's
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(254)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT c.TABLE_NAME,c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, c.CONSTRAINT_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS c WHERE c.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG=DB_NAME() AND c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME 
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tableName, @SchemaName, @constraint

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [' + RTRIM(@SchemaName) + '].[' + RTRIM(@tableName) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint) +']'
    EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT 'dropped constraint : ' + @constraint
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tableName, @SchemaName, @constraint
END
CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
GO

--Set system versioning off

DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(254)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select  t.name as TableName, schema_name(t.schema_id) as SchemaName from sys.tables t where t.temporal_type = 2 
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tableName, @SchemaName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [' + RTRIM(@SchemaName) + '].[' + RTRIM(@tableName) +'] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);'
    EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT 'Removed versioning from: ' + @tableName
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tableName, @SchemaName
END
CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
GO

--Drop all tables

DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(254)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT t.TABLE_NAME, t.TABLE_SCHEMA  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t where t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tableName, @SchemaName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE [' + RTRIM(@SchemaName) + '].[' + RTRIM(@tableName) +']'
    EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT 'Dropped Table: ' + @tableName
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tableName, @SchemaName
END
CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

For me I just do

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 10 --Change this if all tables are not dropped with one run
BEGIN
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = "DROP TABLE ?"
END
```